# Internet not connecting via LAN port (damaged LAN port)

Tags: ethernet, lan

I am a Dell Inspiron N5010 user, and I use wired internet.

Recently, when I tried to remove the ethernet cable from my LAN port, it was not coming out even though I pressed the clip and pulled it. So I tried to remove it carefully, and it came out but the pins of LAN port went inside.

I asked Dell for a replacement as it was under warranty, but they would not.

So how can I fix my LAN port?

Answer (score 1):

You can *try* to bend the pins back in, but I doubt you will have much luck with that.

Buy a USB to ethernet [adapter](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/category/category_slc.asp?MfrId=0&CatId=589) and you should be good to go.